# Angularjs $location undefined inside controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have injected $location service to controller. But $location service is not defined inside method. Please help.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl',['$scope','$location','$mdDialog','MainViewService','$http',
     function($scope, $location,$mdDialog,MainViewService,$http) {
        $scope.pushView = function(){
                    //$location.path
                    //$locaiton undefined <-- Problem
            };
    }]);
```

Comment: I highly doubt that this code is the problem.  Are you sure that you do not have a typo in your code?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the closing bracket!

```
app.controller('MainCtrl',['$scope','$location','$mdDialog','MainViewService','$http',
    function($scope, $location,$mdDialog,MainViewService,$http) {
    $scope.pushView = function(){
                //$location.path
                //$locaiton undefined <-- Problem
        };
}
] // <-- missing closing bracket
);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering....But I forgot to paste ] in question.. there is no syntactical error. And I dnt know what type of dependancy $location requires.. I am not able to find $location object in my controller funtion

Comment: `$location` is an Angular standard service without dependencies. If there is an error then it's not within the code you posted. For further suppor provide a Plunker with your problem.